# Ada rendezvous counterpart in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, ada

So in Ada programming language a rendezvous is a method of inter-process synchronization/message-passing. How do I implement this mechanism in java (along with task suspending and selective wait)? I was looking at java's remote method invocation and Exchanger class but I'm yet to find a suitable solution.

Comment: Given that Java's concurrency features are low-level (and error-prone), it should be possible to implement the equivalent of Ada's high-level concurrency features using them. The question is how much effort your project will allow you to expend on it. If you really need rendezvous semantics, perhaps you should work up estimates of how long it would take to implement the desired behavior in Ada and in Java and present it to those in control of the budget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not familiar with ada but a quick google on *ada rendezvous* suggests you may be looking for one of the [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) implementations, possibly [SynchronousQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html).

Perhaps if you describe what you want to happen when a message is passed we could help more.

Comment: I decided to go with SynchronousQueue and (looks like) it works. Basically I had an assignment to implement an 8-shaped track where cars can be spawned and run on it. I had to make sure they don't crash at the intersection. Car threads make calls to Track process to ask if they can move forward, and if 2 cars arrive at the intersection, a random one is permitted to go through if the intersection is empty.

Comment: @kbijoch - Happy to help but your description sounds more like you are looking more for a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) or a [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) but if the `SynchronousQueue` works for you then go for it.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but my professor told us specifically to implement Ada's rendezvous. I don't know motivation behid this but he said my solution is ok so whatever.

Answer (score 4):

The hardest parts to implement in Java will be selective wait and entry queuing. A blocking queue is an approximate simulation of a protected entry in Ada, without a selective wait.

I do not believe there is any equivalent to the Ada select statement in Java. There is also no way to provide the equivalent to an entry queue with programmer selectable queuing policy. The Java wait/notify combination will activate a waiting thread, but you never know which one. The thread actually activated by a notify command is based upon race conditions, and has the effect of being apparently random. Analysis shows that every waiting thread can be *expected* to be activated through a notify at some point in program execution, but there is no guarantee in Java about the order of thread activation, or even if a given thread will ever activate from a wait state.

Answer (score 1):

you would need an event queue type with a peekWait() function: (disclaimer: this is just a sketch. its not real code).

```
public class EventSemaphore<Event_T>
{
   public void signal(Event_T t);
   public Event_T    wait();
   public Event_T    peekWait();   // returns the signalled value if there is one, otherwise returns null and skips.

   // atomic signal requestQ and wait on responseQ
   public static Return_T signalAndWait<Signal_T,Return_T> (EventSemaphore<Signal_T> requestQ, Signal_T sigVal, EventSemaphore<Return_T> responseQ);   
}
```

an entry has two such events:

```
public class Entry<Param_T,Return_T>
{
   EventSemaphore<Param_T> request_Q = new EventSemaphore<Param_T>();
   EventSemaphore<Return_T> response_Q = new EventSemaphore<Return_T>();
}
```

so suppose that we have a task that looks like this:

```
task serverTask is
   entry foo(x:integer) returns integer;
end serverTask;

task body serverTask is
...
begin
   loop
      select
         when guardOnFoo() =>
            accept foo(x) returns integer do
               ...
               return z; -- not sure if thats the correct syntax
            end foo;
```

may be implemented as

```
public class serverTask extends Thread
{
  Entry<Integer,Integer> foo;   // EDIT: add missing ;

  public void execute()
  {
     while(true)  
     {
        int t;
        if (guardOnFoo() && null!=(t=foo.request_Q.peekWait()))
        {
           // an ada select- statement is actually just a series of if (peekWait()) statements.
           ...
           foo.response_Q.signal(z);
        }
```

so then a client entry call such as

```
r := serverTask.foo(x);
```

becomes

```
r = signalAndWait(serverTask.foo.request_Q,x,serverTask.foo.response_Q);
```

unfortunately, i dont know the exact implementation of EventSemaphore<> and peekWait() off the top of my head, but thats the general idea (at least as i understand it and i may be wrong :lol:).